# SP Char in HTTP Headers?

Tags: http

I've been examining HTTP 1.1 specifications and well I saw something like this:

> Request-Line   = Method SP Request-URI SP HTTP-Version CRLF

I know what this Request-Line stands for but I wonder what `SP` stands for? What kind of character is that?

Link: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1

**Edit:**

In the hope of helping people who visit this page somehow, I found this complete set of codes in the pages provided by the answering people:

```
OCTET          = <any 8-bit sequence of data>
CHAR           = <any US-ASCII character (octets 0 - 127)>
UPALPHA        = <any US-ASCII uppercase letter "A".."Z">
LOALPHA        = <any US-ASCII lowercase letter "a".."z">
ALPHA          = UPALPHA | LOALPHA
DIGIT          = <any US-ASCII digit "0".."9">
CTL            = <any US-ASCII control character
                 (octets 0 - 31) and DEL (127)>
CR             = <US-ASCII CR, carriage return (13)>
LF             = <US-ASCII LF, linefeed (10)>
SP             = <US-ASCII SP, space (32)>
HT             = <US-ASCII HT, horizontal-tab (9)>
<">            = <US-ASCII double-quote mark (34)>
```

They become important as they're being used buy the specifications to explain the formats of the headers and many other things as well.

Comment: I believe it means a space character.

Comment: Had you looked at http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html instead, the "SP" would have been hyperlinked to the definition.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

SP = US-ASCII SP, space (32)

source http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html